# Laravel blade 3 levels quote issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

Anyone know what's wrong with the following quote structure?

```
onclick="showMemberList('{{ $result[\'_id\'] }}')"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '"_id\"]); ?>"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

I thought my structure is correct already where I escaped the `'` wrapping `_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not need to escape the `_id` quotes:

```
onclick="showMemberList('{{ $result['_id'] }}')"
```

Comment: This is to my surprise... I thought without escaping, the _id will become like a constant instead of string